# slow sudo is causing ansible to timeout, related to socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_AUDIT) - Protocol not supported

Tags: raspbian-stretch

> Update: looking at the source for sudo, it seems that the `socket(AF_NETLINK...)` call, happens after the sudo'ed command returned, so it's likely the title/error message is a red-herring....

I have several rpis which are managed with ansible. Intermittently, the ansible job fails with the following message;

```
TASK [Install package] **************************
task path: /ansible/machine-raspberrypi-00007.yml:10
fatal: [raspberrypi-00007]: FAILED! =>
  msg: 'Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: '
```

This seems to correspond to the pi failing to complete the sudo within the ansible timeout. The output from `strace` suggests that there is around an 18 second delay while it tries to open a `netlink` socket during the `sudo`;

```
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_AUDIT) = -1 EPROTONOSUPPORT (Protocol not supported)
```

Here is some more context....

```
17:03:46 munmap(0xb6f9d000, 1069)       = 0
17:03:46 close(5)                       = 0
17:03:46 close(4)                       = 0
17:04:04 socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_AUDIT) = -1 EPROTONOSUPPORT (Protocol not supported)
17:04:04 clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb6fa5068) = 6862
17:04:04 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
17:04:04 rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x12ed8, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0xb6e156b0}, NULL, 8) = 0
17:04:04 rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x12ed8, sa_mask=[],
```

What does this correspond to? and can it be disabled? (assuming that whatever it's trying to do is unsupported on the pi)

Output from `dmesg` for kernel and hardware;

```
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.14.50+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611)) #1122 Tue Jun 19 12:21:21 BST 2018
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv6-compatible processor [410fb767] revision 7 (ARMv7), cr=00c5387d
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Raspberry Pi Model B Plus Rev 1.2
```

**Edit 1:** added content of `/etc/hosts` `/etc/hostname` etc...

```
pi@raspberrypi-00007:~ $ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1     raspberrypi-00007 

pi@raspberrypi-00007:~ $ cat /etc/hostname
raspberrypi-00007

pi@raspberrypi-00007:~ $ hostname --fqdn
raspberrypi-00007

pi@raspberrypi-00007:~ $ hostname
raspberrypi-00007
```

Comment: do the names in /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname match?

Comment: Yep. I pasted in the output into the question for reference...